# How to change all AJAX requests to add token header from cookies

Tags: javascript, ajax, header, http-headers, catch-all

I need to send all my XHR requests with a header named `token` and value coming from cookies.
I found a solution, but the code is very very long - and a bit ugly (insert a full external library - so big - just to use a simple function...)

The need to use `swagger-ui`. I get the token from ADFS by clicking on Authorize btn. But for all the others request (test performed using `try it out` btn)

Because I was not able to find a solution with the Swagger configuration, I decide to use a workaround: Change all the AJAX request on the fly.

I already tried to do it using `Jquery` or direct `Javascript` codes, but none of them were working.

Finally, I find a solution using `XHook` (v1.4.9 - https://github.com/jpillora/xhook)

Here is the code of my file (injected into the index page)

```js
// XHook - v1.4.9 - https://github.com/jpillora/xhook
// Jaime Pillora <dev@jpillora.com> - MIT Copyright 2018
(function (a, b) { var c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H = [].indexOf || function (a) { for (var b = 0, c = this.length; b < c; b++)if (b in this && this[b] === a) return b; return -1 }; q = null, q = "undefined" != typeof WorkerGlobalScope && self instanceof WorkerGlobalScope ? self : "undefined" != typeof global ? global : a, x = q.document, d = "before", c = "after", o = "readyState", n = "addEventListener", m = "removeEventListener", h = "dispatchEvent", u = "XMLHttpRequest", g = "fetch", i = "FormData", p = ["load", "loadend", "loadstart"], e = ["progress", "abort", "error", "timeout"], E = "undefined" != typeof navigator && navigator.useragent ? navigator.userAgent : "", A = parseInt((/msie (\d+)/.exec(E.toLowerCase()) || [])[1]), isNaN(A) && (A = parseInt((/trident\/.*; rv:(\d+)/.exec(E.toLowerCase()) || [])[1])), (G = Array.prototype).indexOf || (G.indexOf = function (a) { var b, c, d, e; for (b = d = 0, e = this.length; d < e; b = ++d)if (c = this[b], c === a) return b; return -1 }), D = function (a, b) { return Array.prototype.slice.call(a, b) }, w = function (a) { return "returnValue" === a || "totalSize" === a || "position" === a }, z = function (a, b) { var c; for (c in a) if (a[c], !w(c)) try { b[c] = a[c] } catch (a) { } return b }, B = function (a) { return void 0 === a ? null : a }, C = function (a, b, c) { var d, e, f, g; for (e = function (a) { return function (d) { var e, f, g; e = {}; for (f in d) w(f) || (g = d[f], e[f] = g === b ? c : g); return c[h](a, e) } }, f = 0, g = a.length; f < g; f++)d = a[f], c._has(d) && (b["on" + d] = e(d)) }, y = function (a) { var b; if (x && null != x.createEventObject) return b = x.createEventObject(), b.type = a, b; try { return new Event(a) } catch (b) { return { type: a } } }, f = function (a) { var c, d, e; return d = {}, e = function (a) { return d[a] || [] }, c = {}, c[n] = function (a, c, f) { d[a] = e(a), d[a].indexOf(c) >= 0 || (f = f === b ? d[a].length : f, d[a].splice(f, 0, c)) }, c[m] = function (a, c) { var f; if (a === b) return void (d = {}); c === b && (d[a] = []), f = e(a).indexOf(c), f !== -1 && e(a).splice(f, 1) }, c[h] = function () { var b, d, f, g, h, i, j, k; for (b = D(arguments), d = b.shift(), a || (b[0] = z(b[0], y(d))), g = c["on" + d], g && g.apply(c, b), k = e(d).concat(e("*")), f = i = 0, j = k.length; i < j; f = ++i)h = k[f], h.apply(c, b) }, c._has = function (a) { return !(!d[a] && !c["on" + a]) }, a && (c.listeners = function (a) { return D(e(a)) }, c.on = c[n], c.off = c[m], c.fire = c[h], c.once = function (a, b) { var d; return d = function () { return c.off(a, d), b.apply(null, arguments) }, c.on(a, d) }, c.destroy = function () { return d = {} }), c }, F = f(!0), F.EventEmitter = f, F[d] = function (a, b) { if (a.length < 1 || a.length > 2) throw "invalid hook"; return F[n](d, a, b) }, F[c] = function (a, b) { if (a.length < 2 || a.length > 3) throw "invalid hook"; return F[n](c, a, b) }, F.enable = function () { q[u] = t, "function" == typeof r && (q[g] = r), k && (q[i] = s) }, F.disable = function () { q[u] = F[u], q[g] = F[g], k && (q[i] = k) }, v = F.headers = function (a, b) { var c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k; switch (null == b && (b = {}), typeof a) { case "object": d = []; for (e in a) g = a[e], f = e.toLowerCase(), d.push(f + ":\t" + g); return d.join("\n") + "\n"; case "string": for (d = a.split("\n"), i = 0, j = d.length; i < j; i++)c = d[i], /([^:]+):\s*(.+)/.test(c) && (f = null != (k = RegExp.$1) ? k.toLowerCase() : void 0, h = RegExp.$2, null == b[f] && (b[f] = h)); return b } }, k = q[i], s = function (a) { var b; this.fd = a ? new k(a) : new k, this.form = a, b = [], Object.defineProperty(this, "entries", { get: function () { var c; return c = a ? D(a.querySelectorAll("input,select")).filter(function (a) { var b; return "checkbox" !== (b = a.type) && "radio" !== b || a.checked }).map(function (a) { return [a.name, "file" === a.type ? a.files : a.value] }) : [], c.concat(b) } }), this.append = function (a) { return function () { var c; return c = D(arguments), b.push(c), a.fd.append.apply(a.fd, c) } }(this) }, k && (F[i] = k, q[i] = s), l = q[u], F[u] = l, t = q[u] = function () { var a, b, g, i, j, k, l, m, q, r, t, w, x, y, D, E, G, I, J, K, L; a = -1, I = new F[u], t = {}, y = null, l = void 0, D = void 0, w = void 0, r = function () { var b, c, d, e; if (w.status = y || I.status, y === a && A < 10 || (w.statusText = I.statusText), y !== a) { e = v(I.getAllResponseHeaders()); for (b in e) d = e[b], w.headers[b] || (c = b.toLowerCase(), w.headers[c] = d) } }, q = function () { if (I.responseType && "text" !== I.responseType) "document" === I.responseType ? (w.xml = I.responseXML, w.data = I.responseXML) : w.data = I.response; else { w.text = I.responseText, w.data = I.responseText; try { w.xml = I.responseXML } catch (a) { } } "responseURL" in I && (w.finalUrl = I.responseURL) }, G = function () { k.status = w.status, k.statusText = w.statusText }, E = function () { "text" in w && (k.responseText = w.text), "xml" in w && (k.responseXML = w.xml), "data" in w && (k.response = w.data), "finalUrl" in w && (k.responseURL = w.finalUrl) }, i = function (a) { for (; a > b && b < 4;)k[o] = ++b, 1 === b && k[h]("loadstart", {}), 2 === b && G(), 4 === b && (G(), E()), k[h]("readystatechange", {}), 4 === b && (t.async === !1 ? g() : setTimeout(g, 0)) }, g = function () { l || k[h]("load", {}), k[h]("loadend", {}), l && (k[o] = 0) }, b = 0, x = function (a) { var b, d; if (4 !== a) return void i(a); b = F.listeners(c), (d = function () { var a; return b.length ? (a = b.shift(), 2 === a.length ? (a(t, w), d()) : 3 === a.length && t.async ? a(t, w, d) : d()) : i(4) })() }, k = t.xhr = f(), I.onreadystatechange = function (a) { try { 2 === I[o] && r() } catch (a) { } 4 === I[o] && (D = !1, r(), q()), x(I[o]) }, m = function () { l = !0 }, k[n]("error", m), k[n]("timeout", m), k[n]("abort", m), k[n]("progress", function () { b < 3 ? x(3) : k[h]("readystatechange", {}) }), ("withCredentials" in I || F.addWithCredentials) && (k.withCredentials = !1), k.status = 0, L = e.concat(p); for (J = 0, K = L.length; J < K; J++)j = L[J], k["on" + j] = null; return k.open = function (a, c, d, e, f) { b = 0, l = !1, D = !1, t.headers = {}, t.headerNames = {}, t.status = 0, w = {}, w.headers = {}, t.method = a, t.url = c, t.async = d !== !1, t.user = e, t.pass = f, x(1) }, k.send = function (a) { var b, c, f, g, h, i, j, l; for (l = ["type", "timeout", "withCredentials"], i = 0, j = l.length; i < j; i++)c = l[i], f = "type" === c ? "responseType" : c, f in k && (t[c] = k[f]); t.body = a, h = function () { var a, b, d, g, h, i; for (C(e, I, k), k.upload && C(e.concat(p), I.upload, k.upload), D = !0, I.open(t.method, t.url, t.async, t.user, t.pass), h = ["type", "timeout", "withCredentials"], d = 0, g = h.length; d < g; d++)c = h[d], f = "type" === c ? "responseType" : c, c in t && (I[f] = t[c]); i = t.headers; for (a in i) b = i[a], a && I.setRequestHeader(a, b); t.body instanceof s && (t.body = t.body.fd), I.send(t.body) }, b = F.listeners(d), (g = function () { var a, c; return b.length ? (a = function (a) { if ("object" == typeof a && ("number" == typeof a.status || "number" == typeof w.status)) return z(a, w), H.call(a, "data") < 0 && (a.data = a.response || a.text), void x(4); g() }, a.head = function (a) { return z(a, w), x(2) }, a.progress = function (a) { return z(a, w), x(3) }, c = b.shift(), 1 === c.length ? a(c(t)) : 2 === c.length && t.async ? c(t, a) : a()) : h() })() }, k.abort = function () { y = a, D ? I.abort() : k[h]("abort", {}) }, k.setRequestHeader = function (a, b) { var c, d; c = null != a ? a.toLowerCase() : void 0, d = t.headerNames[c] = t.headerNames[c] || a, t.headers[d] && (b = t.headers[d] + ", " + b), t.headers[d] = b }, k.getResponseHeader = function (a) { var b; return b = null != a ? a.toLowerCase() : void 0, B(w.headers[b]) }, k.getAllResponseHeaders = function () { return B(v(w.headers)) }, I.overrideMimeType && (k.overrideMimeType = function () { return I.overrideMimeType.apply(I, arguments) }), I.upload && (k.upload = t.upload = f()), k.UNSENT = 0, k.OPENED = 1, k.HEADERS_RECEIVED = 2, k.LOADING = 3, k.DONE = 4, k.response = "", k.responseText = "", k.responseXML = null, k.readyState = 0, k.statusText = "", k }, "function" == typeof q[g] && (j = q[g], F[g] = j, r = q[g] = function (a, b) { var e, f, g; return null == b && (b = { headers: {} }), b.url = a, g = null, f = F.listeners(d), e = F.listeners(c), new Promise(function (a, c) { var d, h, i, k, l; h = function () { return b.body instanceof s && (b.body = b.body.fd), b.headers && (b.headers = new Headers(b.headers)), g || (g = new Request(b.url, b)), z(b, g) }, i = function (b) { var c; return e.length ? (c = e.shift(), 2 === c.length ? (c(h(), b), i(b)) : 3 === c.length ? c(h(), b, i) : i(b)) : a(b) }, d = function (b) { var c; if (void 0 !== b) return c = new Response(b.body || b.text, b), a(c), void i(c); k() }, k = function () { var a; return f.length ? (a = f.shift(), 1 === a.length ? d(a(b)) : 2 === a.length ? a(h(), d) : void 0) : void l() }, l = function () { return j(h()).then(function (a) { return i(a) }).catch(function (a) { return i(a), c(a) }) }, k() }) }), t.UNSENT = 0, t.OPENED = 1, t.HEADERS_RECEIVED = 2, t.LOADING = 3, t.DONE = 4, "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define("xhook", [], function () { return F }) : "object" == typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = { xhook: F } : q && (q.xhook = F) }).call(this, window);

// Extract the {name} value from the cookies (used to find token)
function check_cookie_name(name) {
    debugger;
    var match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'));
    if (match) {
        return match[2];
    }
    else {
        console.log('-- try to call API without authentication token ---');
        return "Please login"
    }
}

// Add token in header before each request
xhook.before(function (request) {
    request.headers['token'] = check_cookie_name('token');
});
```

The actual result is good, and it works.
I expect to find a better/cleaner way to do the same thing ^^

Thank you in advance,
Regards
Nicolas

Comment: This is the code in native JS I tried to use
`
(function () {
    var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
        console.log('request started!');
        this.addEventListener('load', function () {
            console.log('request completed!');
            console.log(this.readyState); //will always be 4 (ajax is completed successfully)
            console.log(this.responseText); //whatever the response was
        });
        origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
`

Comment: I opened a new issue in GitHub related to this lib: https://github.com/jpillora/xhook/issues/101

Comment: The author (jpillora) responded this is not possible. I'm still believing this is possible, maybe not with this library, but with the same js code...
Let close this ticket, and use this full lib.
Pfff: We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.